# Using ggplot to make a heatmap places tiles in incorrect order

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

This is likely due to some silly error but I have been able to produce a reprex of my initial problem so hopefully someone can help.

My goal is to create a heatmap of the upper triangle of a correlation plot, but something is happening when turning the data long and plotting it where the NA values are not creating a nice triangle on the top.

[image]

I've played around with turning the variables into factors and manually setting axis breaks, but can't figure out the issue. Thanks in advance!

Reprex code:

```
fake.cor <- cor(iris[,1:4])
fake.cor[upper.tri(fake.cor)] <- NA
#get in long form
fake.cor.df <- data.frame(fake.cor,
                             var1 = row.names(fake.cor)) %>%
  reshape2::melt(variable.name = "var2" , value.name = "spearman") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(var1, var2), function(x) factor(x, levels = c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")))


ggplot(fake.cor.df, aes(x = var1, y = var2, fill = spearman)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")) +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Petal.Length"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manual set the order of `factor` column you need to set the levels properly

```
fake.cor.df <- data.frame(fake.cor,
  var1 = row.names(fake.cor)) %>%
  reshape2::melt(variable.name = "var2" , value.name = "spearman") %>%
  mutate(var1 =  factor(var1, levels = rev(c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"))),
    var2 = factor(var2, levels = rev(levels(var1))))


ggplot(fake.cor.df, aes(x = var1, y = var2, fill = spearman)) +
  geom_tile()
```

Output
[image]

Comment: This does fix my reprex, but not my actual problem, which makes me think it is something specific to my dataset. Thanks though!